# Creating documentation comments

Tags: pycharm

Somehow on Alt+Enter I don't get the "Insert documentation string stub" option that I expected from [help pages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-documentation-comments.html)

I only see 4 options as below

[image]

I've checked under "Python Integrated Tools" and Google docstring format is enabled, yet I don't see how to insert the Google docstring-styled strings, any idea where else to look?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it doesn't work when the method/function name is selected. I created a ticket in PyCharms' bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36117